# Infinitegraph DB stopping on Docker

Tags: database, docker

Was anybody able to run  Infinitegraph database on a docker container?

#### My docker files:

```
Dockerfile:

FROM ubuntu:latest

# install java
ENV JAVA_VERSION 11
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-${JAVA_VERSION}-openjdk-amd64
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-${JAVA_VERSION}-jdk
RUN update-alternatives --config java && update-alternatives --config javac
RUN java -version
ENV PATH $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

# install infinite graph
RUN apt-get install -y unzip
ENV IG_INSTALLER zip-linux-gcc53-*
ENV IG_HOME /opt/infinitegraph
RUN mkdir -p ${IG_HOME}
COPY ${IG_INSTALLER} ${IG_HOME}
RUN unzip -qd ${IG_HOME} ${IG_HOME}/${IG_INSTALLER}
ENV PATH ${IG_HOME}/bin:$PATH

EXPOSE 8190

# run infinite graph
CMD exec objy startlockserver -noscm & exec objy startstudioserver > /var/log/infinitegraph.log 2>&1
```

```
docker-compose.yaml:

version: "3.0"
services:

  infinitegraph:
    build: 
      context: ./infinitegraph
    container_name: infinitegraph
    ports:
    - "4000:8190"
    restart: unless-stopped
    # detach: true
```

#### Problem:

InfiniteGraph database is starting successfully but then it exits and I cannot access it from localhost:4000.

docker compose logs are:

```
yanis@LAPTOP-QHAEST0S:/mnt/c/Users/Yanis/Desktop/project_IASD$ docker-compose up --build infinitegraph
[+] Building 1.6s (14/14) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                            0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 765B                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                               0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                                1.3s
 => [auth] library/ubuntu:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                   0.0s
 => [1/8] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest@sha256:0bced47fffa3361afa981854fcabcd4577cd43cebbb808cea2b1f33a3dd7f508          0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                               0.1s
 => => transferring context: 57B                                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [2/8] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [3/8] RUN update-alternatives --config java && update-alternatives --config javac                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [4/8] RUN java -version                                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [5/8] RUN apt-get install -y unzip                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [6/8] RUN mkdir -p /opt/infinitegraph                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [7/8] COPY zip-linux-gcc53-* /opt/infinitegraph                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [8/8] RUN unzip -qd /opt/infinitegraph /opt/infinitegraph/zip-linux-gcc53-*                                          0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                          0.1s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:2ed0f20f546270f073983e159a6925e29bf8bcacf75481257c3097bb58b2acb6                                    0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/project_iasd-infinitegraph                                                                   0.0s
[+] Running 1/1
 ✔ Container infinitegraph  Recreated                                                                                           0.3s
Attaching to infinitegraph
infinitegraph  | InfiniteGraph (TM) Start Lock Server, Version: 2022.1
infinitegraph  | Copyright (c) Objectivity, Inc 2012, 2022. All rights reserved.
infinitegraph  |
infinitegraph  | Warning: Unable to open /usr/spool/objy/oolsrec.log
infinitegraph  | Lock Server has been started.
infinitegraph  | Success.
infinitegraph exited with code 0
```

#### Things I tried:

- chatgpt suggests the latter so I tried adding exec part in Dockerfile CMD command

> In Docker, containers are expected to run a foreground process, and if
> the process specified in the CMD or ENTRYPOINT exits, the container
> will stop.
>
> The problem might be that the "objy startstudioserver" command is
> running in the foreground and keeping the container running, but the
> "objy startlockserver" command might be running in the background and
> immediately exiting, which causes the container to stop

- InfiniteGraph DB is working properly when running from localhost

Comment: The paragraph you quote is reasonable advice.  Normally a container only runs a single process; can you run the two servers in two separate containers, based on the same image (same Compose `build:`) but overriding the `command:` on one of them?

Comment: tried that but doesnt work...
Momentarily tho as lockserver is up i can see the service is up but when i refresh its down again.
Code is https://snipboard.io/a0iLNA.jpg (tell me if its more convient to provide it in text form)